# Why libcxx's condition_variable is constexpr and noexcept, but in The Standard it is not?

Tags: c++, stl, language-lawyer, condition-variable

https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/__mutex_base#L290

```
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS condition_variable
{
    __libcpp_condvar_t __cv_ = _LIBCPP_CONDVAR_INITIALIZER;
public:
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR condition_variable() _NOEXCEPT = default;
```

but The Standard declares it as

```
class condition_variable {
public:
    condition_variable();
    ~condition_variable();
```

( http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf )

And `condition_variable()` may throw.

Is libcxx incompatible with C++ Standard, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An implementation is allowed to add `noexcept` to a non-virtual function if it wont ever throw an exception, see [[res.on.exception.handling]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conforming#res.on.exception.handling-5) of the C++17 standard (draft N4659).

However an implementation is not allowed to add `constexpr` to a function. See [[constexpr.functions]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conforming#constexpr.functions-1). See also [LWG issue 2013](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2013).

`std::condition_variable::condition_variable()` is specified as neither `constexpr`, nor `noexcept`, but there are no circumstances under which it *must* throw an exception. See [[thread.condition.condvar]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/thread.condition#condvar).

So, `noexcept` is fine, but `constexpr` is not. However, functions being marked `constexpr` that shouldn't be, is a common non-conformance. For example GCC declares math functions deliberately `constexpr` although they are not supposed to be.